# Javascript: Cannot move back in HTML Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where a user can enter a URL but I wanted to have it automatically remove spaces.

To do this I have the following jQuery function:

```
$('#URL').on('change keyup', function() {
  var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(' ', '');
  $(this).val(sanitized);
});
```

But the problem with this code is that you cannot use the arrow keys to move in the input. i.e. if I type in `http://oogle.com` and I want to use arrow keys to fix my spelling mistake, it will automatically keep the cursor on the very last character. On top of this, I cannot use Ctrl+A to select all the text.

Is there a way to have jQuery/Javascript automatically remove spaces while still being able to move around the input or select it all?

Here is my **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LdrmLmt/)** showing my issue.

Comment: Detect which key was pressed on keyup and do nothing on arrow keys.

Comment: The `keyup` events hold true even for the arrow keys. Hence your function is being called.

Comment: Jesus, why the downvotes. This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Bijan Does my answer work? Can you tell? As I don't understand why am I being downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keypress` instead of `keyup`, so only characters are caught.  In this case, discard a space if it is pressed.

Also check for a paste event, and use a regular expression to replace *all* spaces.  Change the value within a timeout in order to capture the pasted value:

```
$('#URL')
  .on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 32) return false;
  })
  .on('paste', function() {
    $self= $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $self.val($self.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
    });
  });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wv5L9dug/)

Comment: Nopes. This doesn't do.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: This works fine but typically people enter spaces in URLs because when they copy a URL they accidentally have a leading or trailing space and your code wont prevent it from being pasted

Comment: Thanks, that's a valid critique.

Comment: @Bijan Does my answer work? Can you tell? As I don't understand why am I being downvoted.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Your code does not work if they paste in the URL that has spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, all.  I think I have a better solution now.

Comment: This works perfect! Would it be beneficial to replace the regex with `/\s/g`? to remove all whitespace instead of spaces?

Comment: That's a great point, but it's *not* perfect after all.  If the cursor is moved and a character pressed, the cursor jumps to the end.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I *think* I finally have it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/8LdrmLmt/5/)

You can:

1. Record the cursor position
2. Execute your original code
3. Then restore the cursor position

#### Update:

Make sure to change your `.replace` to `.replace(/\ /g, "")`

#### Update 2 (cursor position):

This fixes the cursor position when inserting spaces.

For example copy and pasting the following will now work with any cursor position:

- 
- `341   10365`
- `34  1 1 03  65`

First you need to get the string to the left of the cursor:

```
 var leftString = $(this).val().substring(0, start);
```

Then you need to count the spaces in that string:

```
var leftSpaces = (leftString.match(/ /g) || []).length;
```

Then subtract `leftSpaces` from the `start` and `end` variables.

### Javascript

```
$('#URL').on('change keyup', function() {
  // Store cursor position
  var start = this.selectionStart;
  var end = this.selectionEnd;

  // Check for newly inserted spaces
  var leftString = $(this).val().substring(0, start);
  var leftSpaces = (leftString.match(/ /g) || []).length;
  newStart = start - leftSpaces;
  newEnd = end - leftSpaces;

  // Original Code
  var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/\ /g, "");
  $(this).val(sanitized);

  // Place cursor in correct position
  this.setSelectionRange(newStart, newEnd);

});
```

Comment: Edit: Using `.replace(/\s/g,'');` seems to remove all spaces

Comment: Updated the `.replace`

Comment: This is a great solution, but if you move the cursor before the end and then press the space bar, the cursor will travel right.

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock Thanks! I just updated it to account for inserting spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to add a delay after the keyup event

```
$('#URL').on('change keyup', function() {
  delay(function(){
      var sanitized = $('#URL').val().replace(' ', '');
        $('#URL').val(sanitized);
    }, 1000 );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xv2e9bLe/

Comment: For future reference this is usually called debouncing and in some libraries like underscore there's functions exactly for this.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to adjust user input in a form is done when user finish their input or edit. It's pretty awkward to adjust user input on the fly. So, the onBlur event usually the best event to catch and sanitize a form input.

Based on the answer from adriancarriger, I use the 'blur' event which catch the user input after the user finish the input and do something else.

```
$('#URL').on('blur', function() {
  var start = this.selectionStart,
  end = this.selectionEnd;

  var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/\ /g, "");
  $(this).val(sanitized);

  this.setSelectionRange(start, end);

});
```

This should work well. If you have a real form submit, you can also catch the user input at onSubmit event of the form as well. Note that onSubmit happens at the form object, not the input object.

Comment: From a usability standpoint, this is a good answer.  Note that you can remove the "selection" code.